# A question about the quotient of a $K$-algebra by its radical.

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, modules

Let $A$ be a $K$-algebra and $B=A/\operatorname{rad} A$, where $\operatorname{rad}A$ is the radical of $A$ (intersection of all maximal right ideals of $A$).  Let $e$ be an idempotent of  $A$ and $\bar{e}=e+\operatorname{rad} A$. How to show that $eA/\operatorname{rad} eA$ is isomorphic to $\bar{e}B$? We have $\bar{e}B=(e+\operatorname{rad} A)(A/\operatorname{rad} A)$. The elements in $\bar{e}B$ is of the form $ea+\operatorname{rad} A$, where $a \in A$. But the elements of $eA/\operatorname{rad} eA$ is of the form $ea+\operatorname{rad} eA$, where $a \in A$. This question comes from the reading of the book (page 21, line 1 of the proof of Proposition 4.5 of the book [Elements of the Representation Theory of Associative Algebras: Volume 1](http://books.google.com.hk/books?id=ayNHpi3tYhQC&printsec=frontcover&hl=zh-CN&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)). Another question is how to show that $\operatorname{rad} eA = eA \operatorname{rad} A = e \operatorname{rad} A$? Thank you very much.

> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Prequel:** How to show that $\operatorname{rad}eA=eA\operatorname{rad} A=e\operatorname{rad}A\subseteq \operatorname{rad} A$?

The last two (in)equalities follow from the fact that $\operatorname{rad}A$ is a left ideal. For the first equality you just note that $\operatorname{rad} A=\operatorname{rad} eA\oplus \operatorname{rad} (1-e)A$ (in fact it holds that $\operatorname{rad}$ is compatible with every direct sum decomposition) Furthermore note $A\operatorname{rad} A=\operatorname{rad} A$ and that $A\operatorname{rad} A=eA\operatorname{rad} A\oplus (1-e)A\operatorname{rad} A$ (again in fact this compatibility holds for every direct sum decomposition). Now if you compose all this equalities and use that this is a direct sum decomposition you get the result. (More details in the case of left modules can e.g. be found in [Ringel, Schröer: Representation theory of algebras I](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/schroer/dst/dst_2009.pdf).

**Original Answer:** I assume (now) you know the following: $\operatorname{rad} eA=e\operatorname{rad} A\subseteq \operatorname{rad} A$.

Then define just the obvious maps between $e(A/\operatorname{rad} A)$ and $eA/\operatorname{rad} eA$.

If just have to show well-definedness (that they are mutually inverse and $A$-module homomorphisms is quite obvious.)

So suppose $ea+x=eb+y$ with $a,b\in A$, $x,y\in \operatorname{rad} A$. Then $e(ea+x)=e(eb+y)$, hence $ea+ex=eb+ey$ and thus $ea=eb \mod \operatorname{rad} eA$.

For the other direction suppose $ea+ex=eb+ey$. Then since $ex, ey\in \operatorname{rad} A$ also the inverse map is well-defined.

Comment: thank you very much. Is it true that $\text{rad} eA \subseteq \text{rad} A$?

Comment: @JianrongLi Yes, look at the first line of my answer.

Comment: I have some question about the proving of $e\text{rad} A = \text{rad} eA$. If we know that $M\oplus N = L \oplus K$, it seems that we cannot obtain $M=L, N=K$ or $M=K, N=L$.

Comment: @JianrongLi Yes, that's right, but you additionally know that both $M$ and $L$ are in $eA$, and $N$ and $K$ are in $(1-e)A$ and $eA$ and $(1-e)A$ form a direct sum decomposition.